# Or tools scheduling problem check if a literal is true

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduling, or-tools, cp-sat

Hello Im using or tools cp sat model to solve a scheduling (timetable) problem.

My model is the following
[image]

an im trying to write the following constraint to stick two lessons when they are at the same day

```
def __lang_special_day_constraint_sticked(self, filtered_lessons, rooms, filtered_timeslots):
    for l in filtered_lessons:
        k = 0
        for r in rooms:
            for i in range(len(filtered_timeslots)):
                if i != 0 and i != len(filtered_timeslots)-1 and (l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i]) in self.tables and (l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i+1]) in self.tables and (l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i-1]) in self.tables:
                    self.model.AddBoolOr([self.tables[(l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i-1])],self.tables[(l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i+1])]]).OnlyEnforceIf(self.tables[(l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i])])
                    if self.tables[(l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i])] == True:
                        break
                elif i == 0 and (l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i]) in self.tables and (l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i+1]) in self.tables:
                    self.model.AddBoolOr([self.tables[(l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i+1])]]).OnlyEnforceIf(self.tables[(l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i])])
                    if self.tables[(l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i])] == True:
                        break
                elif i == (len(filtered_timeslots) - 1) and (l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i]) in self.tables and (l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i-1]) in self.tables:
                    self.model.AddBoolOr([self.tables[(l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i-1])]]).OnlyEnforceIf(self.tables[(l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i])])
                    if self.tables[(l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i])] == True:
                        break
```

My goal is to achieve this part :

```
if self.tables[(l.lesson['id'],r['code'],filtered_timeslots[i])] == True:
    break
```

I know this is not gonna work but i want something similar so when this literal is True i will break from the loop and stop further iterations.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot do imperative programming with the values of the variable found during search.  You need to have one Boolean variable per iteration, manage them correctly, and limit tha active constraints.